# How to swap SBS LR 3D videos?

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg

I have this command

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test.mkv" -c copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:08:00 -sn "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test1.mkv" -c copy -ss 00:08:00 -t 00:08:00 -sn "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test2.mkv" -c copy -ss 00:16:00 -t 00:08:00 -sn "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test3.mkv" -c copy -ss 00:24:00 -sn "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test4.mkv"
```

My goal is to upload them to youtube. Yet I need to swap each pair before converting it, so left becomes right and right becomes left.

I found the complex filter and tried

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test.mkv" -filter:v "crop=1280:720:0:0" -i "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test.mkv" -filter:v "crop=1280:720:1280:0" -filter_complex "pad=in_w*2:in_h, overlay=main_w/2:0, scale=in_w/2:in_h, scale=-1:720" -c:a copy "D:\Neuer Ordner\output.mkv"
```

Which led to

```
Option filter:v (set stream filtergraph) cannot be applied to input file D:\Neuer Ordner\Test.mkv -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to. 
Error parsing options for input file D:\Neuer Ordner\Test.mkv. 
Error opening input files: Invalid argument
```

Which command solves this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test.mkv" \
       -c copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:08:00 
       -metadata stereo_mode=right_left -sn "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test1.mkv" \
       -c copy -ss 00:08:00 -t 00:08:00 \
       -metadata stereo_mode=right_left -sn "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test2.mkv" \
       -c copy -ss 00:16:00 -t 00:08:00 \
       -metadata stereo_mode=right_left -sn "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test3.mkv" \
       -c copy -ss 00:24:00 -metadata stereo_mode=right_left -sn "D:\Neuer Ordner\Test4.mkv"
```